# Как правильно написать уровни вложенности модулей в terraform?

Tags: terraform

У меня есть проект по поднятию инфры в selectel, вот его структура

```
Terraform
    ├── configs
    │   ├── configs.tf
    │   ├── subnet_dev.tf
    │   └── subnet_prod.tf
    ├── dev
    │   ├── testdv-01.tf
    │   ├── testdv-db-01.tf
    │   └── testdv-win-01.tf
    ├── main.tf
    ├── production
    │   ├── sed-01.tf
    │   ├── sed-db-01.tf
    │   └── sed-win-01.tf
    ├── selectel.tf
    ├── terraform.tfstate
    └── terraform.tfstate.backup
```

На каждом уровне модуль configs вызывается только один раз

```
├── production
│   ├── sed-01.tf
```

или

```
├── dev
│  ├── testdv-01.tf
```

А потом эти модули вызываются в корне проекта main.tf

Что вызывает лютый спам в консоли из-за глубокой вложенности

в config лежат сетевые настройки роутера и настройки каждой подсети

Как можно решить данный вопрос для того, чтобы сделать красивую архитектуру, а не держать все в корне проекта как в мусорке?(сейчас к сожалению только так(